# Compact Framework - ListView like control?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have been playing with Compact Framework lately and i need some advice.

I have a collection of items. One of the properties on each item is a string type that holds XML. This XML defines image, font, style etc...

Im looking for a control (similar to listView) that would replace listBox control.

Im not satisfied with listView control, because it is very limited on items level.

The control has to be dynamic enough so that my parser could parse the XML and customise the control. For a start i would like to show an image and perhaps some font styles for each row in the control.

Here is a sample what im trying to achieve:

[image]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://www.shrani.si/f/v/ms/482fFELA/lb.png))</sub>

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenNETCF has a community edition of their [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/CompactFramework/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) which is free for download.

I've used the Smart Device Framework in past projects but I'm not too sure if I used the OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.ListBox2 (see [docs](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/)) which is an owner-drawn list and probably the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could write your own `Custrom Control` providing the desired interfaces.. I'd propose to **inherit** from ListBox.

Comment: before i do that, i want to make sure that there isnt something out there already. Im only learning this stuff, so i think there are far more experienced ppl out there with same problem. I found "owner-drawn listView" that im gonna give it a try. If some1 has a solution please post it here. I would appreciate it alot.